# Wrong Thread Exception

Tags: android, exception, scroll, visibility

whenever I am using

listview.scrollTo(int x,int y) method I am getting an Exception called

android.view.View Root Implementation Called From Wrong Thread Exception: only the original thread that created a hierarchy can touch its views.

May I know what is the problem and what is the solution for this exception?

Answer (score 0):

To update the `listview`, you need to update it from the main thread. You can throw the information to the main thread and update it, using a `Handler`.